# Shouldn't this recursive method end as soon as you get to the return?

Tags: c++, recursion, methods

I would like to know why my output is:

```
a-b-b-b-b-0
```

When I think it should just be `a-1`.

Shouldn't a recursive method end as soon as you get to a return? and why doesn't it here?

I only put the letters with `'-'` to clarify that the returns are being met but not stopping there.

```
#include <stdio.h>            
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void printv(int mask[], int elements[], int n)
{
  int i;
  printf("{ ");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (mask[i])
      printf("%d ", elements[i]);
  printf("}");
}

int next(int mask[], int size)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; (i < size) && mask[i]; i++)
    mask[i] = 0;

  if (i < size) {
    mask[i] = 1;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

void nSubsets(int mask[], int elements[], int size, int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int temp[10], count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //this MUST be here
    temp[i] = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (mask[i])
    {
      count++;

      for (int k = 0; k < 44; k++)
        if (temp[k] == 0)
        {
          temp[k] = elements[i];
          sum += elements[i];
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  if (sum == n)
  {
    cout << "{ ";
    for (int l = 0; l < count; l++)
      cout << temp[l] << " ";
    cout << "}";
  }
}

int isEmptySet(int mask[], int elements[], int size, int n, int sizeRecursion)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int temp[10], count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //this MUST be here
    temp[i] = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (mask[i])
    {
      count++;

      for (int k = 0; k < 44; k++)
        if (temp[k] == 0)
        {
          temp[k] = elements[i];
          sum += elements[i];
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  if (sum == n)
  {
    cout << "a-";

    return 1;
  }

  sizeRecursion--;

  if (sizeRecursion > 0)
  {
    next(mask, size);
    isEmptySet(mask, elements, size, n, sizeRecursion);
  }
  cout << "b-";
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int n, size = 10;
  int elements[size];


  size = 6; n = 5;
  elements[0] = 5;
  elements[1] = 2;
  elements[2] = 3;
  elements[3] = 2;
  elements[4] = 1;
  elements[5] = 1;

  int mask[10];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    mask[i] = 0;

  cout << "Subsets of elements: ";
  printv(mask, elements, size); //this prints first subset
  while (next(mask, size))
    printv(mask, elements, size);

  n = 3;

  cout << "\nSubsets equal to " << n << "\n";

  while (next(mask, size))
    nSubsets(mask, elements, size, n);

  cout << "\n" << isEmptySet(mask, elements, size, n, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It returns to the caller. In this case the caller is itself, so it returns there. Otherwise recursion would be useless.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't a recursive method end as soon as you get to a return? and why doesn't it here?

No, the way it works in general is that when a function call returns, it only returns for *that* function call, and then the immediate caller may continue execution. It doesn't matter whether the function is recursive or not, each function call is separate and each call needs to hit a `return` statement at some point (unless the return type is `void`).

When you have this code

```
  ...

  if(sizeRecursion > 0)
  {
    next(mask,size);
    isEmptySet(mask, elements, size, n,sizeRecursion);   
  }   
  cout<<"b-";
  return 0;
}
```

What's going to happen is, as soon as the recursive call to `isEmptySet` returns, its going to go right to the `cout << "b-";` line and then to `return 0;`. If you don't want that then you should put those in an else block, and maybe also modify the line that calls `isEmptySet` so that it returns the value returned from that call.